# Will LINQ iterate a Stack in LIFO order

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Will LINQ methods iterate the contents of a **Stack** (and in my specific case [Stack<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netcore-2.1)) in LIFO (Last In, First Out) order (ie: the same order one would get popping each element which is the reverse of the order in which they were pushed into the stack). Furthermore, being side-effect free, will it abstain from popping the stack while iterating it?

A simple question, and I would assume Yes & Yes, but one so simple that searching produced great volumes of LINQ and Stack related answers of which none of the innumerable results I browsed specifically answered this case.

Comment: Are you referring to the [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1) class?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The following experiment show that it does follow the Stack's LIFO order.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class DoesLinqIterateAStackInLifo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<char>();
        stack.Push('s');
        stack.Push('e');
        stack.Push('Y');
        Console.WriteLine(stack.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (builder,letter) => builder.Append(letter)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",stack.ToList()));      
        if(stack.Count==3) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("And it will not pop the stack");
        }       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Yes
Yes
And it will not pop the stack
```

Comment: The source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,0782e758de2432f1,references